# What does the white icon mean?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

What does this icon mean? It was released with the Scorched Earth content. I can find no information on it, and I'm not sure what it's a picture of:

[image]

Comment: From what I've read, players are speculating that that is the either an overheating/heat stroke symbol, or a dehydration symbol.
I don't personally play the game much, (I have it on Xbox One), but I would have to agree with the speculations as it looks like a man who appears to be suffering from some sort of heat exhaustion while standing in front of a sun. From [this posting](http://steamcommunity.com/app/346110/discussions/0/343785574514377933/), someone also says that if you hold the `H` key (on PC), it will tell you more information on your HUD.  Hopefully that gives you the answer.

Comment: I agree with Timmy, in my experience it pops up when you are both dehydrated (low on water) and experiencing a severe heat event (is there a flame icon next to it when you see it?)

Comment: The flame icon is overheating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The status is Heat Stroke. Per the [wiki](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Status_Effects#Heat_Stroke):

> This status occurs, on the Scorched Earth map, by being overheated, for too long, without resolving the issue. As heatstroke progresses, you will eventually (50%) be prevented from sprinting and (~80%) start to have cloudy vision and drunken swaying movement, and finally start taking health damage until you die.

Unfortunately, the icon is currently missing from the wiki

But this is also confirmed by a [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/ARKone/comments/50udel/whats_this_icon_on_the_se_map/) and various [youtube videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K31-sr66XVk)

Comment: Labeled as hyperthermia in-game, as pointed out by Brok3n. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

It is the symbol for hyperthermia. If you hold the back button on Xbox it will have text where the icon is telling you that it is hyperthermia and at 1% or however long you have it. And as the previous comment from Timmy, the H key on P.C.

Answer (score 0):

It means that your vision is impaired due to heat. You might be able to notice that when this icon is there, there are slightly visible clear stripes on your screen.

Answer (score -5):

Its from being in the direct sunlight "notice the guy blocking the sun from his eyes

Comment: This answer isn't really adding anything nor is it helpful (much). If you are planning on writing an answer, please be precise and with plenty of detail.